# Get all user infos witht the messenger bot

Tags: facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I've a problem using facebook messenger api (graph), I have a webhook (which is my web server) in PHP that manage my messenger bot page behavior.

I've successfully configured it but I don't know how to get user infos like birthday, last_name, email, gender etc...

I've just the message and the id of the user

```
$senderId = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$messageText = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
```

I suppose that there is no additional datas sent to my webhook, but i've well configured subscriptions for my webhook. How to retrieve all informations about a user chatting with my bot ?

Comment: You can only get some basic information directly via the User Profile API, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile If you need more than that, you have to do it via Graph API - and that means, you need to use Account Linking first, to make the user log in to your app and grant it permissions for the data fields you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was excepting. But i've problem to use user profile API. Do you have sample example for PHP using CURL to user profile API ?

Comment: It is one simple GET request ... examples for that should be plenty on the web.

Comment: **This just doesn't work... (my params are ok) at the end, the variable is empty...**  `$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'.$senderId.'?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&access_token='.$pageAccessToken);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $infosUser = json_decode($result,true);

        $senderFirstname = $infosUser['first_name'];`

Comment: And of course you have tried to simply call that exact same URL (assign it to a variable, and make a debug output of it) in your browser first, to see if that reports any errors …?